# iPhone webView only load when its valid - change ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I'm learning how to code apps. I know how to display webView ;)
But now I want only a part of the screen to be the webView and the rest is for example a mapView. 
If the URL-Request is okay, this View should be loaded. If not another View or View Controller should be loaded, in this there is only the mapView. Maybe with a button action?
The button s in the Background (not visible) and only is pressed (programmatacly) when the webView couldn't be loaded.

Please help me, I have no idea how to do that.

**EDIT:**

```
    - (void)map:(UIWebView *)map didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
    // Hide your webview.
    float margin = 19.0f;
    float margin2 = 0.0f;
    float top = margin;
    float left = margin2;
    float width = self.view.frame.size.width - 2*margin;
    //float hight = self.view.frame.size.height;
    float adHight = 50.0f;
    float mapHight = self.view.frame.size.height - (3*margin+adHight);
    float mapTop = 2*margin+adHight;
    CGRect adRect = CGRectMake(left, top, width, adHight);
    CGRect mapRect = CGRectMake(left, mapTop, width, mapHight);
    self.map.frame = mapRect;
    self.ad.frame = adRect;
    self.ad.hidden = NO;

}
```

this doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set delegate for `UIWebView` and then place this method in your VC.

If your URL request will fail this will call.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
// Hide your webview.
}
```

Comment: Everything perfectly!
But how would it go if only the url request is in the background and then a consequent happens?
Edited my first post.